# Java comparator by using priority for classes that extend a common parent class

Tags: java, guava, comparator

I need to implement several comparators in Java.

I have a lot of known classes, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ..., `An`, which all extends class `A`. What I want to to is a comparator class based on Guava [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#immutableSortedCopy%28java.lang.Iterable%29), like the following:

```
Ordering<A> sorterType1 = new Ordering<A>() {
        // Here, provide a Set or something similar that keeps in memory
        // the class types and the associated priority. 

        @Override
        public int compare(A left, A right) {
           // return -1 if class of left has an higher priority wrt class of right; 
           // return  0 if class of left has the same priority wrt class of right; 
           // return  1, otherwise.
        }
```

Since I need to develop a lot of different comparators, I don't want to put the priority inside the class type, since there are several priorities differentiated for each comparator.
What I'm missing are the parts with comments.

**What is the most effective and efficient implementation of the parts with comments?**

Comment: So does each class contain a single priority value? I.e. parent class has an abstract `getPriority()` method returning an `int`?

Comment: No! The priority must be specified within the Ordering as a final value.

Comment: What order do you want the classes in? Currently, I can't understand how to solve this problem, unless you want a static list as shown in [the answer from Xaerxess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213557/474189).

Comment: Yes, Xaerxess got the point! His solution satisfy my need!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't write compare implementation by yourself, use `Ordering` super powers ([`Ordering#explicit(List)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit%28java.util.List%29) to be exact):

```
List<Class<? extends A>> myOrder = ImmutableList.of(
    A1.class, A4.class, A3.class, A2.class);
Ordering<A> explicitByClassOrdering = Ordering.explicit(myOrder)
    .onResultOf(new Function<A, Class<? extends A>>() {
      @Override public Class<? extends A> apply(A a) {
        return a.getClass();
      }
    });

System.out.println(explicitByClassOrdering.sortedCopy(
    ImmutableList.of(new A3(), new A2(), new A3(), new A1(), new A4())));
// [Test$A1, Test$A4, Test$A3, Test$A3, Test$A2]
```

Comment: @Xaerxess i did not understand the question at all, but I like the answer. :) +1